# Flutter FirebaseFirestore how to convert a QuerySnapshot of a map inside a map?

Tags: flutter, firebase, android-studio, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Here is what I would like to recieve: [image: This is my database (linked_users is a map which contains other maps as an email as name]

I would like to fetch all the data from firebaseFirestore and print it in my flutter app out as a table. With a querySnapshot the data is shown in my console, but the problem is I dont know how to convert it into an object and how to create a streambuilder. Also the next problem is that the names of the maps are different (email-names), so its hard to iliterate thought it.

Is there any way to convert the data into a table?

My streambuilder:

```
 StreamBuilder(
                stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("customers").where("email", isEqualTo: "test@test.com").snapshots(),
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {

                  if (!snapshot.hasData)
                    return new Center(child: Text("Loading"),);

                  else
                    return new Center(child: Text("ABC"));

                },)
```

My RecieveData method:

```
RecieveData() async {

  QuerySnapshot querySnapshot= FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("customers")
      .where("email", isEqualTo: "test@test.com")
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) {
    for (var docSnapshot in querySnapshot.docs) {
      print(docSnapshot.data()["linked_users"]["knutie:maxmann@web:de"]); //only like this way I'm able to fetch the data via email
      print(docSnapshot.data()["linked_users"] );

    }
  }) as QuerySnapshot<Object?>;

}
```

The method revieceData would be useless if theres a way to convert the data directly in the streambuilder to a table.

possible duplications:

- [Mapping a map field object in Firestore in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68012391/mapping-a-map-field-object-in-firestore-in-flutter)
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/swift-codable-data-mapping?hl=de
- [Convert Firestore DocumentSnapshot to Map in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56721694/convert-firestore-documentsnapshot-to-map-in-flutter)
- [Flutter Map inside a Map when fetching from api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70923719/flutter-map-inside-a-map-when-fetching-from-api)

Thanks for the help!

So far have tried to convert the output of the method to a json object which is not possible except you change the string with regex. In addition to that I've tried to create Obejects to let the data convert automaticly